# Authenticate windows Identity with Outlook credentials

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I have a web application with windows authentication enabled.After the successful authentication,  it will display my custom login page for validate my outlook credentials and fetch the calendar items(data are pulled from WCF services) from the outlook to show in the UI. My question is ,  both windows and outlook credentials for every user in the network domain are same. Instead of authenticating two times , is there any way like single sign on - Authenticate windows identity with outlook credentials or vice versa?

Comment: See my answer below please. I also updated it with a link to a tutorial.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Appreciated your help I will try the same and let you.

Answer (score 0):

Your web application will be running within an application pool within IIS. The application pool will be running under an account (mostly this is the Service Account). Therefore, all requests to the web services will be sent with whatever this account is.

If you want to send the user's windows account, you need to use delegation or impersonation so the web site can pass the users credentials to the web service. Then on the webservice, you will need to impersonate the user to get access to their calendar.

This is not a simple task and if you are doing this you need to talk to the system admin boys to set up an account that can impersonate other users. You will also need to enable impersonation on IIS.

Depending on your setup, whether the services and the site reside on the same computer or different computers you may need to use **impersonation** (one computer) or **delegation** (for more than 1 computer). You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647248.aspx) on impersonation and delegation.

You have probably started developing and you are accessing your own outlook calendar, and that is working. But keep in mind you are probably running everything on your own machine. As soon as you deploy it and multiple users are hitting the site and web services, the whole game changes.

**Update**

If you are using Office 365 and have Azure AD, then you can follow [this](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/Tutorial/dotnet) tutorial to do so. But like I said, this is not simple and requires work event if you use this tutorial's method.